# Can a textbox be enabled after a certain value from a picklist is selected

Tags: workflow, validation

I am having a picklist field which has 3 values 1.Web, 2.Mail, 3.Other.If i select other then the text must be editiable. If i select web or mail then the textbox must in uneditiable mode. Kindly tell how to do this.Im using PE

Comment: Did my answer help you along? How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe PE does not have access to Apex, but does have Visualforce. Have a look at this proof of concept I just knocked up:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.type}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="conditionalEntryFieldDiv"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="conditionalEntryFieldDiv">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.accountnumber}" rendered="{!Account.type == 'Prospect'}"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.accountnumber}" rendered="{!Account.type != 'Prospect'}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

When the account is "Prospect" the account number is editable. Otherwise it is read only. Changing the value in the drop down rerenders the panel making the field go from editable to read only and vice versa.
It is not necessary to hit save to trigger the effect
[image: Read only]
[image]

Comment: @ Doug B, thanks for the reply.We tried but getting only blank space. We have given this auto populate field as a text field. Tell me whether it is correct or not. Please tell "Account.accountnumber" is of which field type. Waiting for the reply.

Comment: This example uses standard objects and fields. Account is available in PE. You should be able to use this page as it is in your org to see how it works. Yes, in this case AccountNumber is a text field.

Comment: I have tried this code in my PE but not working.When i tried the same code in DE it is working.

Comment: You might have to do some investigation yourself. Look at how it works on DE, and try to determine what is different on PE. You say it isn't working: is it rendering both the input AND the outputfields? Or neither? Or just one of them? Test out whether rerender works on a simple example. It is standard VF so I believe it should work in PE. That's how I would start, by analysing whether the "rerender" works as expected and whether the "rendered" evaluates properly. If this functionality doesn't work in PE then you will need to solve your problem using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had worked on same issue but little different.The requirement is like i have a picklist with some values.Whenever user selects a value with upgrade user has to fill the other update field. 
I had come up with two solutions to my client.

1.validation rules

I had created two validation rules

Requirement is field will be mandatory,When ever user selects picklist value "Existing Customer - Upgrade" from type

AND(ISPICKVAL(Type,'Existing Customer - Upgrade'), ISBLANK(light_weight__LeadValue__c) )

And whenever user selects any value other than Existing Customer - Upgrade it will give you a exception like don't add any data

AND(NOT(ISBLANK( light_weight__LeadValue__c )), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL( Type,'Existing Customer - Upgrade')))

2.Create a custom visual force page.Whenever user selects the value in the picklist the text field will display automatically.

@Udaya i think it worked for you..