# In VF page how to make a selection Readable or Editable based on the picklist value selected

Tags: visualforce, picklist, fields

I have created a new VF page. In my VF page having Stage picklist same as Opportunity. If we select "Closed Won" then i need to make one a "Invoice selcetion" to editable, if we choose any other value in the picklist then "Invoice Selection" should be readable. I am trying this but didn't get any solution for this, using Salesforce PE. Kindly send any link for this to achieve. Thanks in advance, waiting for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good example of this here, in a recently asked question ["Can a textbox be enabled after a certain value from a picklist is selected"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/can-a-textbox-be-enabled-after-a-certain-value-from-a-picklist-is-selected)