# Enable/disable fields on create page based on picklist value using reRender

Tags: picklist, dynamic-visualforce, fields

I'm creating a Hospital Management application that has a custom object GH_Patient__c. There is a picklist field GH_Patient_Type__c which has 2 values - In-Patient and Out-Patient. 
My Requirement is that

1) when type In-Patient is selected I want the fields Date_Of_Admission and Bed_Assigned to be enabled and Date_of_Visit and Number_of_Visits to be disabled

2) when type Out-Patient is selected I want the fields Date_of_Visit and Number_of_Visits to be enabled and Date_Of_Admission and Bed_Assigned to be disabled

And this should happen without page refresh

I created a VF page to override the New button functionality of the patient object and it is as follows

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="GH_Patient__c" extensions="GH_New_Patient" tabStyle="GH_Patient__c" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="true">

<apex:form >
    <apex:sectionheader title="Patient Edit" subtitle="{!if(GH_Patient__c.Id==null,'New Patient',GH_Patient__c.Name)}"></apex:sectionheader>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Patient Edit" mode="edit" >
        <apex:PageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton title="Save" value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton title="Save & New" value="Save & New" action="{!saveAndNew}"/>
            <apex:commandButton title="Cancel" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:PageBlockButtons>
        <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="patientInformation" title="Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.Name}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Doctor_Assigned__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Patient_Account__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Nurse_Assigned__c}" id="NurseAssigned"/>

            <apex:selectList label="{!$ObjectType.GH_Patient__c.Fields.GH_Patient_Type__c.label}" id="PatientType" size="1"  value="{!getPatientTypeValues}">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectedPatientType}"/>
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!togglePatientType}" reRender="inPatientRequiredFields,outPatientRequiredFields"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="inPatientRequiredFields"  rendered="{!isInPatient}">
               <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Date_of_Admission__c}" id="DateOfAdmission"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Bed_Assigned__c}" id="BedAssigned"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="outPatientRequiredFields" rendered="{!isOutPatient}">
               <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Date_of_Visit__c}" id="DateOfVisit"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Number_of_Visits__c}" id="NumberOfVisits"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Visiting_Hours__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Hospital_Site__c}"/>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        </apex:actionRegion >
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My controller class is as follows

```
public class GH_New_Patient{
public ApexPages.StandardController stdController{get;set;}
public GH_Patient__c newPatient{get;set;}
public boolean isInPatient{get;set;}
public boolean isOutPatient{get;set;}
public string selectedPatientType{get;set;}
public string dateOfAdmission{get;set;}
public string bedAssigned{get;set;}

public GH_New_Patient(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    stdController=sc;
    this.newPatient=(GH_Patient__c)stdController.getRecord();
    isInPatient=false;
    isOutPatient=false;
}

public PageReference saveAndNew(){
    stdController.save();
    PageReference pgRef = new PageReference('/NewPatient?retURL=%2Fa02%2Fo');
    return pgRef;
}

public void togglePatientType(){
String patientType = newPatient.GH_Patient_Type__c;
    if(patientType.equals('In-Patient')){
        isInPatient=true;
        isOutPatient=false;
    }
    else if(patientType.equals('Out-Patient')){
        isInPatient=false;
        isOutPatient=true;
    }
    else{
        isInPatient=false;
        isOutPatient=false;
    }
}


public List<selectOption> getPatientTypeValues() 
{
    List<selectOption> options= new List<selectOption>();
    options.add(new selectOption('', '--None--')); 
    options.add(new selectOption('In-Patient', 'In-Patient')); 
    options.add(new selectOption('Out-Patient', 'Out-Patient')); 
    return options; 

}


}
```

When i save the VF page i get the following error:

> Error: Unknown property
>   'GH_Patient__cStandardController.getPatientTypeValues'

I have tried to match the requirements using Javascript as well but it wasn't rendering the page the way I wanted it. I know the error that I'm getting right now is related to the extension controller ie GH_New_Patient class methods not being called but I just want an approach that will help me to meet the requirements either by using Javascript or apex code. any links or suggestions are welcome
I'm new to Salesforce and need to submit this project in a week. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Good example here using actionsupport

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/can-a-textbox-be-enabled-after-a-certain-value-from-a-picklist-is-selected

Comment: I tried using action script. This is my latest code <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Patient_Type__c}" id="PatientType" required="true"> <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="inPatientRequiredFields,DateOfAdmission,BedAssigned,outPatientRequiredFields,DateOfVisit,NumberOfVisits"/> </apex:inputField> <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="inPatientRequiredFields" rendered="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Patient_Type__c == 'In-Patient'}"> <apex:inputField value="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Date_of_Admission__c}" id="DateOfAdmission" rendered="{!GH_Patient__c.GH_Patient_Type__c == 'In-Patient'}"/> <apex:in